# Confusion with state of parameter in recursion with javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, factorial

[Gif for the debugger in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSZ44.gif)

So, when running this, i'm a bit confused how `fac` parameter is maintaing the state. what i understand by factorial(4) is

1. `4 * (4-1) // 4 * 3 = 12`
2. `12 * (3-1) // 12 * 2 = 24`
3. `24 * (2-1) // 24 * 1 = 24`

```
function factorial(fac){
  debugger
  if(fac == 1)
    return fac
  return fac * factorial(fac-1)
}
factorial(4)
```

Comment: It's not maintaining any state, the function is being called several times recursively

Comment: so, how does it understand what is the current value of parameter, i'm trying to clear as much as possible.

Comment: The state is in the function call stack that JS manages for you. You probably understand it better, if you transform `factorial` to a tail recursive function, which doesn't rely on the stack. Hint: you need a second argument as an accumulator where the multiplication takes place.

Comment: @Nick Sure it does maintain the state of the `fac` variable during the recursive call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `factorial` has its **own** `fac` parameter, with its own value.  So when, in the first call (during `factorial(4)`), when you do:

```
return fac * factorial(fac - 1);
```

that **calls** `factorial` again, passing in the value resulting from `fac - 1` (`3`). That new call receives `fac = 3` and does its work with it. While that's happening, the first call is waiting to get the return value from it (let's call it `retVal`) so it can finish the `return fac * ____________` by plugging `retVal` in where `____________` is.

Eventually, a call to `factorial` does its work by returning `fac` instead of calling `factorial` again, which means the one that called it can complete its work and return its return value, which means the one that called *it* can do that, until we get back to the top one that returns the overall result.

Here's an attempt to show how the calls stack up (using indentation for showing the recursive calls):

```
factorial(fac = 4)
    factorial(fac = 3)
        factorial(fac = 2)
            factorial(fac = 1)
            return 1
                   |
                   v
        return 2 * 1 = 2
                       |
               +−−−−−−−+
               |
               v
    return 3 * 2 = 6
                   |
           +−−−−−−−+
           |
           v
return 4 * 6  = 24
```

Note that when `factorial(1)` is running, there are **four different** `fac` parameters in memory, `fac = 4` (the outermost call), `fac = 3` (the first recursive call), `fac = 2` (the next recursive call), and `fac = 1` (the last recursive call before the returns kick in).

Answer (score 0):

Think of the function calls as stack, so when fac(4) is called this stack is formed

```
factorial(1)
     ^
Calls^
     ^
factorial(2)
     ^
Calls^
     ^  
factorial(3)
     ^
Calls^
     ^
factorial(4)
```

then this stack is resolved from top down. so value of fac is being changed at every call

```
factorial(1) ==> fac = 1, return value =1 
then resolves 
factorial(2) ==> fac = 2, return value =2*factorial(1) > already in memory
then resolves
factorial(3) ==> fac = 3, return value =3*factorial(2) -> in memory
then resolves
factorial(4) ==> fac = 4, return value =4*factorial(3) -> in memory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify pure expressions the same way you can simplify mathematical  expressions.

```js
  factorial(4)
= 4 * factorial(4 - 1)             // because 4 != 1
= 4 * factorial(3)
= 4 * (3 * factorial(3 - 1))       // because 3 != 1
= 4 * (3 * factorial(2))
= 4 * (3 * (2 * factorial(2 - 1))) // because 2 != 1
= 4 * (3 * (2 * factorial(1)))
= 4 * (3 * (2 * 1))                // because 1 == 1
= 4 * (3 * 2)
= 4 * 6
= 24
```

This is a very powerful way of reasoning about expressions. It's [one of the advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) of writing pure code instead of impure code. You can't simplify impure expressions in this manner because impure code  has  side effects which need to be tracked.

Anyway, why don't you try to simplify the following `result` expression by yourself? It'll help you understand how recursion works in functional programs. No need to think about function call stacks or anything else technical. Just get a pen and paper and start simplifying the expression like you would do in your 5th grade math class.

```js
function fib(n) {
    if (n === 0) return 1;
    if (n === 1) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

const result = fib(5);

console.log(result); // 8
```

A few tips to remember.

1. When replacing a function call with its result, wrap it in parentheses.
2. Always simplify the leftmost expression first. This mimics the way JavaScript works.
3. Simplify expressions one at a time. Don't simplify multiple expressions in a single step.